# How to map list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 list below

```
Token_Sentence=[['This','is','a','book'],['This','is','a','cat'],['Those','are','two','books']]
Mapping=[['This',1],['is',2],['a',3],['book',4],['cat',5],['Those',6],['are',7],['two',8],['books',9]]
```

And I want to map Token_Sentence (convert text to index number) like this

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[6,7,8,9]]
```

and here is my code

```
for a in range(len(Token_Sentence)):
    for b in range(len(Token_Sentence[a])):
        for c in range(len(Mapping)):
            if Token_Sentence[a][b]==Mapping[c][0]:
                Token_Sentence[a][b]=Mapping[c][1]
```

But the Problem is it's take a very long time to run (my real data list is pretty large).

Is there are other ways to achieve my goal that faster and simpler than I did?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a mapping from `Mapping`:

```
Token_Sentence=[['This','is','a','book'],['This','is','a','cat'],['Those','are','two','books']]
Mapping=[['This',1],['is',2],['a',3],['book',4],['cat',5],['Those',6],['are',7],['two',8],['books',9]]
d = dict(Mapping)
new_sentence = [[d[b] for b in i] for i in Token_Sentence]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out, another name for the abstract data type "dictionary" implemented by `dict` is called often called *a map*. Indeed, in Python, a `dict` is a [mapping type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Comment: I'll note that this is especially performant because `dict` has a lookup of O(1) instead of O(n), so overall your complexity is O(n), rather than O(n*m)

Answer (score 0):

Above Answer is good , Just wanted to show if you want without converting to dict :

```
Token_Sentence=[['This','is','a','book'],['This','is','a','cat'],['Those','are','two','books']]
Mapping=[['This',1],['is',2],['a',3],['book',4],['cat',5],['Those',6],['are',7],['two',8],['books',9]]

print([[k[1] for j in i for k in Mapping if j==k[0]] for i in Token_Sentence ])
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```